# Using python pandas module in Eclipse Mars

Tags: java, eclipse, python-2.7, pydev

I am combining java and python code in Eclipse and when I want to execute python script that contains pandas module called from java class I get `null` value. Otherwise, if I am not using pandas module, but just simple python script everything works fine. I assume `PyDev` interpreter properly and paths to all python modules are configured properly since I do not get any import error and I can get an module info when I cover mouse over it in the code.

All modules are in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages.

Please check `java class`, `python script` and `PyDev` configurations:

```
package test4;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test4 {

public static void main(String a[]){
    try{

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/local/bin/python2.7","solinor_final.py");
    Process p = pb.start();
    System.out.println("Hello");
    String line = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
    BufferedReader in = null;

    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        while((line=in.readLine())!=null) {
            sb.append(line);
            System.out.println(line);

        }


    } finally {

        in.close();
    }


    System.out.println("value is : "+sb);

    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
    }

}
```

Python:

```
    import sys

    sys.path.append("/usr/local/bin")
    sys.path.append("/usr/bin/")
       sys.path.append('/Users/quuppa/Documents/workspace/test4/report1.csv')


import pandas as pd   


def main():
    import python_class as so
    print "Hello inside"

    data = pd.read_csv("report1.csv",sep=",",header=None)
    data = data.rename(columns={0:'Merchant name',1:'Business ID',2:'Main merchant ID',3:'Report type',4:'Report search date',5:'Report period',\
                            6:'Outlet name',7:'Address',8:'Number of transactions',9:'Value of transactions',10:'Commission',11:'Chargebacks and adjustments',12:'Settlement value'})

    data = data.drop([data.index[0]])

    bd = so.Solinor(data)

    total_amount = bd.totalAmount()
    print total_amount

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

These are the outputs with and without including pandas module:

```
Hello
value is :

Hello
Hello inside
value is : Hello inside
```

Configuration image:

[image]

Do you have any suggestion what could be a problem in running the code with pandas module?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution for this problem. The most efficient way is just to use ProcessBuilder without PyDev and PYTHONPATH settings. The necessary modifications are to add in ProcessBuilder first argument to be full path to python installation, in my case this is in */usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7*, and second argument to be full path to main python script.

The second modification is to place python scripts outside Eclipse workspace and pass the full path as a second argument in ProcessBuilder to the main python script. I assume that PyDev somehow has a problem in reading libraries written in C such as numpy.

Answer (score 0):

Some things that feel wrong for me which you can investigate:

1. the PYTHONPATH you're setting is something you shouldn't do in your script, rather, have the PYTHONPATH set from the outside (or in PyDev, let it manage it for you) -- also, no reason to put the report1.csv in the PYTHONPATH (i.e.: don't put things in sys.path).
2. pd.read_csv("report1.csv",sep=",",header=None): use the full path for report1.csv.
3. create a separate project for your code -- don't put it into /usr/local/bin/python2.7.

Still, I'm not really sure what's wrong, but my suggestion would be first making it work in plain Python (so, use the pydev debugger to run your python code and debug what's wrong) and only after that think about integrating it into java/jython (make sure you read the Getting started manual http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_root.html to set things up properly to run in the debugger).

Comment: Thanks Fabio! I did everything you said and now PyDev reports `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Integral'`, for `numbers module` which is part of `numpy module`,  when I am running python which is very strange.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below steps also. I got this from a [blog](https://klaith.wordpress.com/2009/06/12/pydev-unresolved-import-errors/), and that is really helpful to me. However the steps are...

1st download and install Anaconda 2.x and then as below

The only thing for me that solved the issue was to completely delete (window->preferences->pydev->interpreter python->remove) and then adding it again with Auto Config.

if you have some package is not installed then just run this command in console 
`conda install <package_name>` it will be downloaded and should works instantly.